# How do I trigger LUIS in all dialogs retaining the previous context?

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, azure-language-understanding

I am developing a bot with Microsoft Bot Framework, LUIS and node.js .This bot is based on Microsoft Teams and I am using `TeamsBotSsoPrompt` and `Microsoft-Graph` for authentication of the user.

The authentication step in the `AUTH_DIALOG` is as follows:

```
async showUserInfo(stepContext) {

    const tokenResponse = stepContext.result;
    if (tokenResponse) {
      try {

        // Call Microsoft Graph on behalf of user
        const oboCredential = new OnBehalfOfUserCredential(tokenResponse.ssoToken);
        //console.log("oboCredential> " + JSON.stringify(oboCredential));
        const graphClient = createMicrosoftGraphClient(oboCredential, this.requiredScopes);
        const me = await graphClient.api("/me").get();
        const lanID = await graphClient.api("/me/onPremisesSamAccountName").get();
        if (me) {

          var authHeaders = {
            "user": me.userPrincipalName,
            "token": tokenResponse.token,
            header1: null,
            header2: null,
            header3: null,
          }

          userName = me.givenName;

          authHeaders['name'] = userName;

          await stepContext.context.sendActivity({ type: ActivityTypes.Typing });
          await stepContext.context.sendActivity(`Hello! <b>` + userName + `</b>`);
          await stepContext.context.sendActivity({ type: ActivityTypes.Typing });
          await stepContext.context.sendActivity("Let's get started.How can I help you?");
          return await stepContext.beginDialog(FLOW_DIALOG, authHeaders);

        } else {
          await stepContext.context.sendActivity({ type: ActivityTypes.Typing });
          await stepContext.context.sendActivity("Getting profile from Microsoft Graph failed! ");
          return await stepContext.endDialog();
        }
      }
      catch (error) {
           // error logged here
      }
    }
    else {
      await stepContext.context.sendActivity({ type: ActivityTypes.Typing });
      await stepContext.context.sendActivity("Login was not successful please try again.");
      return await stepContext.endDialog();
    }
  }
```

The `FLOW_DIALOG` is where I have LUIS enabled.From the `FLOW_DIALOG`, I redirect the bot to other dialogs based on the `Intent`.But when I am in that other dialog and if I enter something in the bot, the current dialog ends and returns the flow to the `FLOW_DIALOG`. I want all the dialogs to trigger LUIS and move the flow to the correct `Intent` Dialog.

The `FLOW_DIALOG` is as follows:

```
async introStep(stepContext) {
    const ActionCard = utility.createSuggestedActions(suggestionList, suggestionTitle);
    await stepContext.context.sendActivity({ type: ActivityTypes.Typing });
    await stepContext.context.sendActivity({ attachments: [ActionCard] });
    return { status: DialogTurnStatus.waiting };
}

async actStep(stepContext) {
    const luisRecognizer = new LuisRecogniser(luisConfig, stepContext.dialogs.telemetryClient);
    let authHeaders = stepContext.options;
    if (!luisRecognizer.isConfigured) {
        return await stepContext.context.sendActivity("Something went wrong. Please Contact Your Administrator");
    }
    
    const luisResult = await luisRecognizer.executeLuisQuery(stepContext.result ? stepContext.result : stepContext.context);
    topIntent = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(luisResult);
    switch (topIntent) {
        case "Intent1": {
            authHeaders['header1'] = luisResult.entities;
            return await stepContext.beginDialog(DIALOG_A, authHeaders);
        }
        case "Intent2": {
            authHeaders['header2'] = luisResult.entities;
            return await stepContext.beginDialog(DIALOG_B, authHeaders);
        }
        // ... and other intents in similar way
    }
}
```

Now, I did try adding the LUIS to the `onMessage` call but I couldn't access the `context.options`   to set or reset the `authHeaders` that I have. I know the context there is `DialogContext` and the one we get access to is `TurnContext`.

So is it possible to alter the headers values and pass it along the dialog calls and also trigger LUIS for every message the user enters from whichever Dialog the user currently has access to.

Comment: You can have a look at this sample to understand more about the dialogs  - [Custom Dialogs Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/19.custom-dialogs/) and to understand more on Teams auth you can refer this - [Teams auth sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/46.teams-auth)

Comment: Please refer this doc as well - [Using Dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-waterfall-dialogs?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#using-dialogs)

Comment: Can you help me with an example? I still cannot figure out how do I have LUIS prompted for every message with the samples. I had referred these samples but still couldn't get anywhere close to what I want.

Comment: Can you check by setting this sample - [Core bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/901bc140f5aa300fbfa852e64afd7c65fceebff9/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot). In this sample we have the LUIS implement based on user message the dialogs is chosen and flow gets started.

Comment: Actually I have followed this example only.If you look at the `FLOW_DIALOG` it resembles the same.My concern is when I am directed to a dialog and within that dialog if I type something I should be able to allow LUIS handle it.Then either continue with dialog if no Intent is found else redirect to another dialog.

Comment: One solution I come across is we can add luisRecognizer in each step and start other dialogs based on user input.

Comment: But it seems like it doesn't work when we have ChoicePrompt or ConfrimPrompt however I am still trying it my side. Can confirm that it's working in case of TextPrompt.

Comment: Yeah, I also faced issue with the `ChoicePrompt` and `ConfirmPrompt` . I tried replacing those by `HeroCard` buttons, but it didn't work out.

Comment: Tried same but it's not working. It seems that LUIS integration for each step isn't possible.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'll continue to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Having LUIS integrated within Waterfall dialogs seems not supported. It worked fine in case of TextPrompt but I find no way to do that when we have 'ChoicePrompt' or 'ConfirmPrompt'.

We can have LUIS integrated to decide which dialog to start and for the same sample is also available - [Core bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/901bc140f5aa300fbfa852e64afd7c65fceebff9/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot).

You can also refer this link to have idea on how to use dialogs in bot - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-waterfall-dialogs?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#using-dialogs